# Can I generate a Preview for a Google Drive (custom Realtime) file for use in Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

[How to generate preview of documents saved in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479239/how-to-generate-preview-of-documents-saved-in-google-drive)
asks effectively the same question as this.

However...

1. The answer was 'no'
2. Its an old question and Google Drive SDK has changed a lot since then.
3. It doesn't (explicitly) relate to Realtime files.
4. I also have found nothing in Google's documentation.

So hopefully this is a reasonable question:

Can I generate a preview of my custom Realtime file for Google to show when "Preview" is selected from the right-click menu in Drive? It does show the option to edit the file using my app, but it's an ugly and discouraging screen for the user to find themselves looking at.

(And if a method is to in some way use a thumbnail, when and how should that be generated and passed? Note, this is all client-side.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in support for this in the Realtime API, but it should act just like any other shortcut file.  I *believe* the right answer is thumbnails.  See uploading thumbnails here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/file

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try it. One concern is when the thumbnails are invalidated; apparently this normally happens on _any_ change - which clearly might be an issue for a realtime model.

Comment: I don't think that thumbnails of realtime documents will be invalidated for every change. That refers to binary blob uploads. If it's an issue, let me know..